# Método PHP dentro de un foreach (PDO)

Tags: php, poo, pdo

Estoy intentando que se ejecute una consulta de un método tantas veces como registros haya en otra consulta previa, es decir que copie los registros encontrados con otro id mediante un insert de otro método. Mi pregunta es si es correcto usar este método dentro de un bucle, porque no consigo que ejecute el método copiarFotos de manera recurrente.

```
 $identificadorAlbum = $_POST['id_album'];
 $resultadoB = Fotos::consultaPorIdAlbum($identificadorAlbum);
 $bucle_listaAlbumsB = $resultadoB[0];
 $cont_registroB=0;

 foreach($bucle_listaAlbumsB as $itemB):
   $fechahoy = date('Y-m-d');
   $gestion = new Fotos(''.$itemB['nombre_foto'].'',''.$itemB['descripcion_foto'].'',''.$itemB['archivo'].'',''.$fechahoy.'','',$identificadorAlbum,'');
   $gestion->copiarFotos();
 endforeach;
```

Comment: ¿Podrías explicar mejor el asunto?  No logro entender lo que quieres hacer, aunque de entrada te digo que no conviene ejecutar consultas una y otra vez dentro de un bucle, habiendo mejores métodos de concatenación para hacerlo, o mejor aún si se hace mediante transacciones. Si el bucle se hace infinito por ejemplo terminará tumbado la base de datos y el sistema o si son varios miles de interacciones y la consulta que se ejecuta es lenta. Además ¿qué pasa si falla por la mitad?  ¿Cómo controlarás luego los que se insertaron y los que no se insertaron?

Comment: Necesito efectuar la acción de copiar las fotos de un ID a otro ID previamente seleccionado. No se me ocurre cómo.

Comment: Tu comentario no aclara mucho. Si es copiar de *un*  id a *otro*  id, ¿por qué un bucle si se trata de una sola fila? Además, si las dos tablas tiene un elemento común, el `UPDATE` o el `INSERT` se pueden hacer en una sola consulta, lanzando una sub-consulta que traiga los datos de la tabla donde los mismos existen para ponerlos en la otra.

Comment: La acción se trata de copiar masivamente x fotos de un álbum a otro, por lo que intento recuperar el número de registros del álbum A así como sus datos nombre, archivo, para hacer un INSERT en B con ellos tantas veces como registros hay en A. Tanto el origen como el destino los defino en el formulario en envío de datos.